# How to troubleshoot and enable folder synchronisation in Laravel Homestead?

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I have followed instructions (https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/homestead) to set up laravel running in a Vagrant/Homestead box.
In the end, I should be able to the website from virtual machine by accessing homestead.app in browser on my host machine.

I´ve tried accessing in different ways, with and without specifying port 8000:

http://homestead.app - connection timeout
http://192.168.10.10 - connection timeout
http://localhost - connection timeout
http://127.0.0.1 - **connection refused**

After troubleshooting I have found that files are not synced to the virtual machine.
E:\homestead_local\Laravel\public\ contains index.php which I try to access. It is not synced to the VM.

I can´t find any error logs on server.

Also, on VM home/vagrant folder was empty after I did everything from instructions. I´m not sure if that was supposed to happen.

---

Instructions of what I did, keeping them short:

1. Installed Virtualbox 4.2 and Vagrant 1.8.1
2. Dowloaded vagrant box:

   ```
   vagrant box add laravel/homestead
   ```
3. Installed Homestead 0.4.1

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/laravel/homestead.git Homestead
   ```
4. Initialized homestead:

   ```
   bash init.sh
   ```
5. Edited homestead.yaml file
6. Edited hosts file

---

Hosts file:

```
192.168.10.10           homestead.app
127.0.0.1               homestead.app
```

homestead.yaml file:

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 768
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: E:\HSprojects
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public

databases:
    - homestead
```

---

Questions

1. After running "vagrant up" my CMD shows this:

   ....
   default: Mounting shared folders...
   default: /vagrant => E:/Homestead

Why is it showing E:/Homestead and not E:/HSProjects?

2. Is sharing between folders bidirectional? I can't find a clear answer on this, but I assume they are.

Comment: Why do you have the line `127.0.0.1               homestead.app`?

Comment: One related discussion I found suggested doing that.

Comment: Maybe silly question but did you do the vagrant up command?

Comment: I would get rid of the map in your hosts file to 127.0.0.1 I think this is from inside the virtual box so won't make sense to the host machine

Comment: Yes, I'm using vagrant reload --provision after applying changes, and I'm also using vagrant halt/up a lot. I have also tried removing vagrant/homestead and installing anew. Will try again tomorrow.

Comment: I've tried it with and without 127.0.0.1 in hosts file.